# How to aggregate the ranked data?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a data set that shows the top 10 books with the relative price changes (`(p2 - p1) / p1`) as I've shown below:

```
df <- tribble(
~book_id,  ~p1, ~p2,  ~change_in_p,
  1,         3,   5,     0.667,
  2,         4,   6,     0.5,
  3,         8,   9,     0.125,
  4,         1,   1,     0,
  5,         3,   4,     0.333, 
  6,         8,   8,     0,
  7,         3,   5,     0.667,
  8,         4,   6,     0.5,
  9,         8,   9,     0.125, 
 10,         1,   1,     0,
)
```

Now I want to aggregate the price changes into 4 mutually exclusive groups:

```
1. No change
2. <50% increase
3. 50 - 69.99% increase
4. >=70% increase
```

and according to the top 2, top 5, top 7 and top 10 books.

For example, the percentage of books in the top 2 that have increased in price by 0% is 0%. Both (100%) increased in price by between 51 - 70%.

For the top 5, 20% (1/5) were no change, 40% increased by <50% and 40% increase by between 50 and 69% etc.

Here is the desired data:

```
desired_df <- tribble(
  ~top,      ~no_change, ~betw_0.0001_5_perc_change, ~betw_5_7_perc_change,  ~more_7_per_change,
 'top2',        "0%",              "0%",                 '100%',                '0%',
 'top5',       "20%",             "40%",                 '40%',                 '0%',
 'top7',      "28.6%",          "28.6%",                '42.9%',                 '0%',
 'top10',      "30%",             "30%",                  '40%',                 '0%',
)
```

**What did I do so far?**

Since I could not group the books such as top 2, top5, top7, top10, I've basically looked at all data:

```
labels = c('less_5_perc_change', 'betw_5_7_perc_change',  'more_7_per_change')

df%>% 
  group_by(cols = cut(change_in_p, breaks = c(-Inf, 0.49, 0.69, Inf), labels = labels)) %>% 
  summarise(n = n_distinct(book_id)) %>% 
  mutate(pct = scales::percent(n/sum(n), 1)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = cols, names_from = cols, values_from = pct)
```

Unfortunately, I could not manage to get my desired data.

Comment: Could you show the code of what you already tried?

Comment: Who closed this?!

Comment: I really don't understand why it's closed. If something is not clear, they basically can ask where the unclear point is. @Edward

Comment: It's very clear to me. I was just about to post the answer too. Sigh.

Comment: But your percentages are wrong for the last two rows (I think). All rows should sum to 100%.

Comment: Ah yes, it was a rough calculation by myself. I've just corrected it. @Edward

Comment: And I think you want 0, 0-49%, 50-69%, 70%+. ??

Comment: Definitely! @Edward

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209461/discussion-between-zineda-and-edward).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your correction. @Edward

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using **dplyr**, I create the `top` variable, summarise the percentage changes, calculate the cumulative sums, and convert to percentages.

```
library(dplyr)

pct <- function(x, top) paste0(round(cumsum(x)*100/top,1),"%")

df %>%
  mutate(top = ifelse(book_id<=2, 2, 
                      ifelse(book_id<=5,5,
                             ifelse(book_id<=7,7,10)))) %>% 
  group_by(top) %>%
  summarise(no_change = sum(change_in_p==0),
            betw_0_50_perc_change=sum(change_in_p>0 & change_in_p<0.5),
            betw_51_70_perc_change=sum(change_in_p>=0.5 & change_in_p<0.7),
            more_70_perc_change=sum(change_in_p>=0.7)) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-top), ~pct(., top))  # convert to % for all vars except top
```

---

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
    top no_change betw_0_50_perc_change betw_51_70_perc_change more_70_perc_change
  <dbl> <chr>     <chr>                 <chr>                  <chr>              
1     2 0%        0%                    100%                   0%                 
2     5 20%       40%                   40%                    0%                 
3     7 28.6%     28.6%                 42.9%                  0%                 
4    10 30%       30%                   40%                    0%
```

Answer (score 2):

An idea via base R can be to loop over 2, 5, 7, 10 which will represent the number of rows each, then use `cut` to find the intervals and simply use the `prop.table` function to calculate the frequencies, i.e.

```
x<- c(2, 5, 7, 10)
labels1 = c('no_change' ,'less_5_perc_change', 'betw_5_7_perc_change', 'more_7_per_change')

d2 <- do.call(rbind, 
   lapply(x, function(i) { i1 <- df[seq(i),]; 
         i2 <- cut(i1$change_in_p, breaks = c(-Inf, 0, 0.49, 0.69, Inf), labels = labels1);
         paste0(round(prop.table(table(i2))*100, 1), '%')}))
```

which gives,

> ```
>      [,1]    [,2]    [,3]    [,4]
> [1,] "0%"    "0%"    "100%"  "0%"
> [2,] "20%"   "40%"   "40%"   "0%"
> [3,] "28.6%" "28.6%" "42.9%" "0%"
> [4,] "30%"   "30%"   "40%"   "0%"
> ```

To tidy up and bring it to the format you desire, then

```
setNames(data.frame(cbind(paste0('top', x)), d2), c('top', labels1))
```

which finally gives,

```
    top no_change less_5_perc_change betw_5_7_perc_change more_7_per_change
1  top2        0%                 0%                 100%                0%
2  top5       20%                40%                  40%                0%
3  top7     28.6%              28.6%                42.9%                0%
4 top10       30%                30%                  40%                0%
```